# Undefined name 'TextSearchOption' FusionSync Flutter PDF Viewer

Tags: flutter, syncfusion, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

I wanted to load a PDF in my application. For this, I used the SyncFusion PDF Viewer plugin. Everything worked perfectly till this error came up when I tried to add a search bar

> Undefined name 'TextSearchOption'. Try correcting the name to one that
> is defined, or defining the name.
> My Code

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer/pdfviewer.dart';
class pdfvw extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;
    const pdfvw ({ Key? key, required this.url }): super(key: key);
  @override
  _pdfvw  createState() => _pdfvw(); 
}
class _pdfvw extends State<pdfvw> {
  late PdfViewerController _pdfViewerController;
late PdfTextSearchResult _searchResult;

@override
void initState() {
    _pdfViewerController = PdfViewerController();
    _searchResult = PdfTextSearchResult();
    super.initState();
}


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Syncfusion Flutter PDF Viewer'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () async {
              _searchResult = await _pdfViewerController.searchText('the',
                  searchOption: TextSearchOption.caseSensitive);
              setState(() {});
            },
          ),          
          Visibility(
            visible: _searchResult.hasResult,
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.keyboard_arrow_up,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                  _searchResult.previousInstance();
              },
            ),
          ),
          Visibility(
            visible: _searchResult.hasResult,
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                _searchResult.nextInstance();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: SfPdfViewer.asset(widget.url),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reported issue is due to not importing the dependency package. When using the TextSearchOption parameter, you need to import the **‘package:syncfusion_flutter_pdf/pdf.dart’** in your sample. For more information, please refer to the following UG documentation link,

https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/pdf-viewer/text-search